# Unicorn swallowing USR2 signals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, signals, unicorn

Our unicorn process completely swallows USR2 signals. It appears to do absolutely nothing.

There is absolutely nothing logged in unicorn.log when the signal is sent. It is not the Gemfile error that usually causes this problem.

Unicorn responds to other signals just fine (USR1, QUIT, etc)

There was one guy online that had the same problem, and we ended up using his "solution":

```
before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap('USR2') do
    server.send(:reexec)
  end
end
```

This ends up calling the same thing as it would normally: https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/20f3b0c94474709fc6468a8a707b1c205ca80677/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb#L306-307

This solution works but obviously feels quite hacky. There is something else going on here. I ran a `grep` on all of the gems on the system and the only ones that mention USR2 are Unicorn and raindrops (dependency of Unicorn). I don't know how this signal is being swallowed.

This is a Ruby 2.0.0p0 Rails 4 application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unicorn restart issue with capistrano](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330577/unicorn-restart-issue-with-capistrano)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checking back in here - the solution was the same as [Unicorn restart issue with capistrano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330577/unicorn-restart-issue-with-capistrano), we completely missed that part of the Unicorn documentation.